# installing firebase tools doesn't work on mac

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I install firebase-tools with npm
but terminal can't find firebase-tools :(...
also I tried auto installing script "curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash" but this also give me this error  "This tool has encountered an error."
what should i do?

```html
KangTaeui-MacBook-Pro-2:practice_react kangtaegeun$ sudo npm install firebase-tools -g
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
/Users/kangtaegeun/.npm-global/bin/firebase -> /Users/kangtaegeun/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js

> protobufjs@6.10.1 postinstall /Users/kangtaegeun/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall

+ firebase-tools@8.9.0
added 593 packages from 364 contributors in 32.084s
KangTaeui-MacBook-Pro-2:practice_react kangtaegeun$ firebase
-bash: /usr/local/bin/firebase: No such file or directory
KangTaeui-MacBook-Pro-2:practice_react kangtaegeun$
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, do not share pictures of text or code.  Copy the text into question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: What do `env | grep firebase` and `which firebase` say? Pretty sure it's being installed by root somewhere your user account can't access. Might consider using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) so you can get around all the sudo permissions issues. Also, you may need sudo for the curl install as well. Hard to say without more info.

Comment: I tried env | rem firebase but nothing came out  please tell me how to do with nvm